# Embedded Jetty can't do a GET to my resource files

Tags: embedded-jetty, sni

I'm in the process of using SNI with embedded Jetty with a webAppContext.  For the most part, this is working fine.  I've switched to version 9.4.8 of Jetty.

The service starts up just fine in regards to SNI and correctly loads everything and reads all the certificates fine.  But when I make specific requests from several browsers that involve JS and image files on my resource path, the browser complains that there is no `GET` defined for those files but has no problem referencing/GETting Controller operations defined with a `@RequestMapping`.

The following code worked fine in previous versions of Jetty but does not now work.  Has Jetty 9.4.8 changed the way that relative references are resolved.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

---

The Jetty code (this has worked for years up to this point)

```
 WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
        Resource webappDir = Resource.newResource(System.getProperty("traffic.app.dir"));
        webAppContext.setBaseResource(webappDir);
        webAppContext.setDescriptor("WEB-INF/web.xml");
        webAppContext.setContextPath("/");
        webAppContext.setParentLoaderPriority(false);
        webAppContext.setLogUrlOnStart(true);
```

and the fragment of html that is now failing is

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/spin.js"></script>`

where the resource path is `file:///f/f2-traffic/webapp/`

The error is

`Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://test2:8000/tools/js/spin.js”.`

`405 Request method 'GET' not supported.`

and the url to the page where all this happens is `http://test2:8000/tools/tsub`

UPDATE

In the web.xml file I have the following

```
...
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
...
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>domainTrafficDispatcher</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Is this an issue?

Comment: Does your `WEB-INF/web.xml` have a `url-pattern` set to `/*` for some servlet or filter?

Comment: Also, [Jetty 9.4.8 is a vulnerable release](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jetty-announce/msg00123.html), use something more recent to get past the CVEs on 9.4.8.

Comment: Will try both suggestions

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Moving to the lastest version of Jetty seems to clean up an apparent error but not fix the problem.

Comment: Did you configure an alternate defaults descriptor?  Are you using a Rest library that does static file serving itself? (if so, have you configured it to not do that?)  Do you have a servlet at `url-pattern` for `/` (or on name `default`)?

Answer (score 0):

@joakimerdfelt SO I have resolved my issue after much hair pulling work.

In the process of fixing this I added a new `Controller` to handle the 'default' references to /js/*, /images/*, etc. and thought that would at least patch the issue.  It didn't.

After much hair pulling it turns out that someone two years ago for a much older version of the software added mappings (to nothing apparently).  I removed those mappings and added security configuration to apply no security when fetching that type of file.  Security applies to all other references. I removed the `Controller` so default handling would be done, and ... it all just started working the way it should.

Thanks for all the suggestions.